# Popup on mousehovor in Table - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Added a class in

```
< td > <span class = "only-show-on-hover" > </ span > </ td >
```

Code for the css class

```
td span.only-show-on-hover { visibility : hidden ; } td:hover span.only-show-on-hover { visibility : visible ; }
```

Code for diaglog box

```
< div class = "bg-white mpd-container brs-6 p-2 pl-4" > < div class = "d-flex" > < div class = "mpd-pic" > < img width = "50" class = "mr-2 mt-2 " src = "assets/images/dummy-user.svg" alt = "" /> </ div > </ div > < div class = "d-flex my-2" > < div class = "profile-completion " > completion will go here </ div > </ div > </ div >
```

How to open popup as given in image[image]

I tried to add the dialogue box but it is showing inside td. I have show like popup as given in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td [ngbPopover]="popContent" [container]="'body'" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">Primary Role</td>

<ng-template #popContent>
<span>Profile</span>
<span>Academic Qualification</span>
<span>Technical Learning (2 Mandatory)</span>
</ng-template>
```

for Reference : [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)
Working: [Example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/popover/tplcontent/stackblitz.html)

Comment: i hope my answer is useful for you.